# NullPointerException when assigning to arr[x][y] in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

I know why there is an error and i have fixed it.. i need someone to explain it properly.. It compiles fine but at runTime it shows Null Pointer Exception at line **appString[i][j] = s[j];**..Some one know the reason...?

```
appString = new String[app.size()][];
for(int i = 0; i<app.size();i++)
{
    Vector appVec = (Vector) app.get(i);
    String[] s = new String[appVec.size()];
    appVec.toArray(s);
    for(int j = 0 ; j<s.length;j++)
    {
        //String s1 = s[j];
        appString[i][j] = s[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've created the *top-level* array, but each element of it is null. You need something like:

```
appString[i] = new String[s.length];
```

inside your loop. Or given that you don't need the array again anyway, you don't need to loop:

```
appString = new String[app.size()][];
for(int i = 0; i<app.size();i++)
{
    Vector appVec = (Vector) app.get(i);
    String[] s = new String[appVec.size()];
    appVec.toArray(s);
    appString[i] = s;
}
```

Comment: @devA: It doesn't show a compile-time error because there's nothing wrong with it at compile-time. You've created an array with element type `String[]`, with a particular size. You just haven't given initialized any of those elements. It's just the same as `Foo[] x = new Foo[10];` - each element is null.

Comment: @devA: I had a typo. Fixed now - try it with the edited code.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jon's solution but a bit shorter.

```
Vector<Vector<String>> app = ...
List<String[]> arrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for(Vector<String> vector: app) 
   arrays.add(vector.toArray(new String[vector.size()]));
appString = arrays.toArray(new String[arrays.size()][]);
```

Comment: I was trying to change the OP's code as little as possible. And `Vector`? Really? :)

Comment: this i have already done.. what i was actually trying do was to get the string array from a method which return a Vector which inturn stores Vector.. Any way thank you..

Comment: @Jon, I wouldn't suggest using Vector either, I assumed this is what was used.  Otherwise, I do tend to go for making the answer as different as possible, there would be no point in repeating your answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Following statement will create a String array with size of app for 1st dimension

```
appString = new String[app.size()][];
```

But all the values for that 2dimensional array will be filled with null.

When `appString[i][j]` is processed at runtime, first `appString[i]` bucket will be looked for and in that appString[i][j] will be looked.

Here `appString[i]` itself is `null` and hence you have got the `NullPointerException`.